# 0-9 and [[:digit:]] will match 1-10, but not more

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script, just for fun which creates a new User and Generates a Password for him.

Now I have to check if the user enters something stupid, instead of a digit.

```
function checkifcorrectnum() {
#Check if the User did something else than enter a number
#And check if the Number is absurdly big

case "$1" in
  [[:digit:]] ) if [ "$1" -gt "255" ]; then echo "Too big!" ; else : ; fi ;;
  *) echo "Please enter a number!"; exit ;;
esac

}
```

But when I run the script, and enter 1-9 it works, but anything higher wont

Comment: The whole script:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx5xXH1384nZQS12VnhoN1U0MWc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only matching for a single digit by just `[[:digit:]]`. The `bash` globbing cannot be used like Regex and match any token any number of times by operators like `*` or `+`. If you want to stick with your method and you know exactly how many digits you want to allow then use e.g. for 2 digits:

```
case "$1" in
  [[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
```

If you are not sure then:

```
case "$1" in
  [[:digit:]]*)
```

`*` expands to any number of character.

But i think you should look at Regex matching offered by `bash` by the `=~` operator of `[[`, so your whole function can be rewritten as:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    [[ $1 -gt 255 ]] && echo "Too big!"
else
    echo 'Please enter a number!' && exit
fi
```

Also as you are not doing anything if the number is `<=255` so `[[ $1 -gt 255 ]] && echo "Too big!"` is enough.

Comment: @DatNoHand `+` is a regex operator which means one or more of the preceding token so `^[[:digit:]]+$` matches if the argument contains only one or more digits.

Comment: @DatNoHand `[[` is a bash keyword that provides more functionalities than [`, Regex based matching is one of those..

Answer (score 0):

Since it is easier to test if a string is *not* a number than to test if it is, I suggest inverting the order of the tests:

```
function checkifcorrectnum() {
  case "$1" in
    *[^[:digit:]]*) echo "Please enter a number";;
    *) [ "$1" -gt "255" ] && echo "Too big!" ;;
  esac;
}
```

The glob `*[^[:digit:]]*` matches if any character in `$1` is not a digit.

Examples:

```
$ checkifcorrectnum 255
$ checkifcorrectnum 256
Too big!
$ checkifcorrectnum 25z
Please enter a number
```

As an aside, the keyword `function` is bash-only and generally not necessary.  With the keyword removed, the code works not only in bash but also in any POSIX compatible shell.

Comment: so you can leave out the if in the 2nd case?

Comment: @DatNoHand Yes, you can leave out the second case.  If you do that, of course, there would be no warning if the number was too big.

Comment: @DatNoHand OK I see what you mean.  Yes, for this case, `[ "$1" -gt "255" ] && echo "Too big!"` is equivalent to `if [ "$1" -gt "255" ]; then echo "Too big!"; fi` but has the advantage of being more compact.  `&&` means logical-AND: the statement following `&&` is executed only if the statement preceding it returned true.